# How can I change the data in the .bak file backed up in MSSQL to insert data format?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

With help from ChatGPT, I received the code below and am checking it, but I don't know why the error occurs. Please help me

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True'
# create connection
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

# backup path
backup_file_path = 'D:\\Test.bak'

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE #TempTable (D VARBINARY(MAX))")

with open(backup_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    backup_data = f.read()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO #TempTable (D) VALUES (?)", backup_data)

select_query = "SELECT data FROM #TempTable"
for row in cursor.execute(select_query):
    backup_data = row[0].decode('utf-8') 

    table_data = backup_data.split("INSERT INTO ")
    for table_insert in table_data[1:]:
        table_name = table_insert.split()[0]
        values_start_index = table_insert.find("VALUES") + len("VALUES")
        table_values = table_insert[values_start_index:].strip().strip(";")
        insert_script = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} {table_values};"
        print(insert_script)

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE #TempTable")

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

> File "D:\Git\temp\convertBakUp2SQL.py", line 18, in 
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TempTable (D) VALUES (?)", backup_data)
> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Warning: Partial insert/update. The insert/update of a text or image column(s) did not succeed. (0) (SQLPutData); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified. (7125)')

The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified. (7125)') I heard that the error can be caused by the file size, so I tested it with a small file, but there was no progress at all.

In doing this, the .bak file backed up in the 2018 version of SQL Server cannot be restored in the 2017 version, so the intention is to restore all data by changing the insert statement. Please help if there is anything that needs to be fixed

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do to be honest. You can't manipulate backup files if that's what you're doing though, they are binary files and supposed to be copy of the sql data. If you want to append data to a backup, you add the data to the server and then take a new backup. What's the actual problem that you want to solve?

Comment: You create an `insert_script` but then all you do is print it? Maybe show us what gets printed? But you have to explain what the code attempts to do, we can hardly reverse engineer code thats not working, to work out how to make it work... and seriously? ChatGPT? Who knows if the code has any relevance to what you asked for.

Comment: Aside... there's no 2018 version of SQL Server, we went from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2019 and then to SQL Server 2022. What's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` on the SQL Server from which the backup file originated, what's the output from the server you're trying to "load" the backup into?

Comment: SQL Server's backup files are binary data in a proprietary format that can encompass the contents of many schema's and table's worth of data. i.e.: You cannot just insert the contents of a .bak file into a table and hope to query it. You're probably looking for the [`RESTORE DATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) command, noting that you cannot restore backups from newer versions of SQL Server onto older versions.

Comment: You can perhaps look into bakpac to see if it can be used to transfer data to older versions

Comment: sorry. The intention was not conveyed accurately. I have the exact same database in mssql 2017 and 2019, but data generated from a certain service was saved in 2019, and I would like to move that data to 2017 and work on it. At this time, since the general recovery method is not possible due to the version difference, we are planning to move all data in 2019 by creating an insert script and executing it in 2017. Knowing how difficult this can be, I tried to find a way to automate it through code.

Comment: Why not just export data from 2019 to 2017 using ssms export data, ssis or just openquery between servers. Your way is way too complicated

Comment: related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions/1311

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?
Every backup file (*.bak) is made by:

- One Primary Data File (*.mdf);
- One Transaction Log File (*.ldf);
- One or more Secondary Data File (*.ndf).

You can verify the integrity/structure of these files by doing:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\\Test.bak'
```

This will show you how many of the above files your *bak file consists of.

It seems that you want to execute a Python script to do your SELECT code (amongst other things) and I'm not understanding your code. Why are you trying to INSERT INTO a temporary table a full backup (*.bak)? You should INSERT INTO a temp table the data that it's inside another table.

So you'll need to actually do the INSERT INTO command, example:

```
    `-- Create a temporary table
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
        ID INT,
        Name NVARCHAR(50)
    );

-- Insert data into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Name)
VALUES (1, 'John'),
       (2, 'Alice'),
       (3, 'Bob');`
```

I hope this helps you understanding what to change to move forward with your issue.